# set header angular http service put

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

Having difficulty with a temporary work around but the intent was to add to a http put request a header with string value, 'username' : 'flastname'. Within the service that invokes the put call, just before the $http.put call, the username header is to be set.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post.username = 'flastname';
            $http.put('http://localhost:8080/xxxxx-integration/api/claims',claim);
```

Server side, retrieving a http header 'username' always results in null and in the even stranger behavior than expected category is random numbers of http put calls are generated. Thought I followed the documentation at: 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

but maybe read it wrong.

Comment: funny thing, the header is being set for 'post' and then a call to 'put' is made. That didn't fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the shortcut method? According to the docs, you should be able to do it like so:
put(url, data, [config]);

```
$http.put('http://localhost:8080/xxxxx-integration/api/claims',claim , {
    headers: {'username': 'flastname'}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = {
 method: 'PUT',
 url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxxx-integration/api/claims',
 headers: {
   'username': 'flastname'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' } // json for data
}
```

now just put the `req` varaible inside `$http` :)

```
$http(req).then(function()...)
```

Comment: going this route has resulted in: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Comment: hit enter too quickly... the code:        myfactory.updateClaim = function(claim) {

         var req = {
     method: 'PUT',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxxxx-integration/api/claims',
     headers: {
        'username': 'flastname'
     },
     data: claim // json for data
   };

  $http(req).then(funtion (result ){
   var two = 1+1;
  }) ;

Comment: the important thing is, you build the hold request packet before hand. i might have have made a syntax error while building the json, that you will have to figure out :P